# Only Integer scalar arrays can be converted to scalar index

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am making a project which needs finger counting from the webcam. I tried implementing the below code but I am getting the error and each time it stops responding after launching the first frame and the console prints the error mentioned below. How to solve this error and warning?

```
#libraries included are numpy, cv2, pairwise    
background= None
accumulated_weight= 0.5
roi_top=30
roi_bottom= 300
roi_left= 600
roi_right= 300

#function to find average background value
def calc_accum_avg(frame, accumulated_weight):
    global background
    if background is None:
        background= frame.copy().astype('float')

    cv2.accumulateWeighted(frame, background, accumulated_weight)    


#Segmenting the contour
def segment(frame, threshold_min=25):
    diff= cv2.absdiff(background.astype('uint8'), frame)
    ret, thresholded= cv2.threshold(diff, threshold_min, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(thresholded.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if len(contours) ==0:
        return None

    else:
        #Assuming that the biggest contour in  ROI(Region of Interest) is Hand itself
        hand_segment= max(contours, key= cv2.contourArea)
        return(thresholded, hand_segment)


def count_fingers(thresholded, hand_segment):
    conv_hull= cv2.convexHull(hand_segment)
    top= tuple(conv_hull[conv_hull[:,:,1].argmin()][0])
    bottom= tuple(conv_hull[conv_hull[:,:,1].argmax()][0])
    left= tuple(conv_hull[conv_hull[:,:,0].argmin()][0])
    right= tuple(conv_hull[conv_hull[:,:,0].argmax()][0])      

    cX= (left[0]+ right[0])//2
    cY=(top[1]+ bottom[1])//2
    distance= pairwise.euclidean_distances([cX, cY], Y= [left, right, top, bottom])[0]
    max_distance= distance.max()
    radius= int(0.9*max_distance)
    circumference= (2*np.pi*radius)
    circular_roi= np.zeros(thresholded[:2], dtype= 'uint8')
    cv2.circle(circular_roi, (cX, cY), radius, 255, 10)
    circular_roi= cv2.bitwise_and(thresholded, thresholded, mask= circular_roi)
    contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(circular_roi.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    count=0

    for cnt in count:
        (x,y, w,h)= cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        out_of_wrist= (cY+ (cY*0.25))>(y+h)
        limit_points= ((circumference*0.25)> cnt.shape[0])

        if out_of_wrist and limit_points:
            count +=1
    return count       


cam= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
num_frames=0

while True:
        ret, frame= cam.read()
        frame_copy= frame.copy()
        roi= frame[roi_top: roi_bottom, roi_right:roi_left]
        gray= cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray= cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(7,7),0)
        if num_frames<60 :
            calc_accum_avg(gray, accumulated_weight)
            if num_frames<=59:
                cv2.putText(frame_copy, 'WAIT, GETTING BACKGROUND',(200,300), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255),2)
                cv2.imshow('Finger Count', frame_copy)

        else:
            hand= segment(gray)
            if hand is not None:
                thresholded, hand_segment= hand
                #Draw contours
                cv2.drawContours(frame_copy, [hand_segment+(roi_right, roi_top)],-1, (255,0,0), 5)
                fingers= count_fingers(thresholded, hand_segment)
                cv2.putText(frame_copy, str(fingers), (70,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1,(0,0,255),2)
                cv2.imshow('Thresholded', thresholded)
        cv2.rectangle(frame_copy, (roi_left, roi_top), (roi_right, roi_bottom), (0,0,255),5)
        num_frames+=1
        cv2.imshow('Finger count', frame_copy)
        k= cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        if k==27:
            break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the error. I am working on Spyder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thresholded is an ndarray, thus so is thresholded[:2]. If you want to create an array of zeros with the same dimensions as thresholded[:2], what you need is zeros_like.

Namely, replace

```
circular_roi= np.zeros(thresholded[:2], dtype= 'uint8')
```

with

```
circular_roi= np.zeros_like(thresholded[:2], dtype= 'uint8')
```

Comment: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:245: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'

Comment: circular_roi= cv2.bitwise_and(thresholded, thresholded, mask= circular_roi)  This above error is being displayed on this line after zeros_like